# Reactive Nested Form

Tags: angular

I am building a CRUD application where from list page edit link is edit:uid, which when routed to edit page onInit

- Constuctor user route.params to get id and make a rest call
- ngonInit create Form structure as per expected json.
- by the time rest returns form is created, hence
- this.form.setValue(json);

json structure is as;

```
{
"id":"xxxxxx",
"address":"256",
"country":"United Kingdom",
"child":[
  {
     "id":"yyyy",
     "option":[
        {
           "id":"zzzzz",
           "title":"gfg"
        }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am struggling to map this to reactive Forms, using angular 7

Comment: This is a very useful and basic guide to solve your problem. Take a look: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Answer (score 0):

you can create you nested form like that where data is you json object

```
userForm = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(''),
  address: new FormControl(''),
  country: new FormControl(''),
  child: new FormGroup({
     id: new FormControl(''),
     option: new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(''),
          state: new FormControl('')
     })
 })
})

this.userForm.patchValue({
 id: data.id,
 address: data.adress
 child : {
   id : data.child.id,
  .......

});
```